# How do I get the strongly-typed value of an OutArgument in code?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation-4.5

Given an `Activity` (created via the designer) that has several `OutArgument` properties, is it possible to get their strongly-typed value from a property after invoking the workflow?

The code looks like this:

```
// generated class
public partial class ActivityFoo : System.Activities.Activity....
{
    ....
    public System.Activities.OutArgument<decimal> Bar { ... }
    public System.Activities.OutArgument<string> Baz { ... }
}

// my class
var activity = new ActivityFoo();
var result = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(activity);

decimal d = activity.Bar.Get(?)
string s = activity.Baz.Get(?)
```

The `T Get()` method on `OutArgument<T>` that requires an `ActivityContext` which I'm not sure how to obtain in code.

I also realize it's possible to get the un-typed values from `result["Bar"]` and `result["Baz"]` and cast them, but I'm hoping there's another way.

*Updated to make it clear there are multiple `Out` values, although the question would still apply even if there was only one.*

Answer (score 0):

If you look at workflows as code, an Activity is no more than a method that receives input arguments and (potentially) returns output arguments.

It happens that Activities allows one to return multiple output arguments, something that C# methods, for example, don't ([actually that's about to change with C# 7 and tuples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/)).

That's why you've an `WorkflowInvoker.Invoke()` overload which returns a `Dictionary<string, object>` because the framework obviously doesn't know what\how many\of what type output arguments you have.

Bottom line, the only way for you to do it fully strong-typed is exactly the same way you would be doing on a normal C# method - **return one OutArgument of a custom type**:

```
public class ActivityFooOutput
{
    public decimal Bar { get; set }
    public decimal Baz { get; set; }
}

// generated class

public partial class ActivityFoo : System.Activities.Activity....
{
    public System.Activities.OutArgument<ActivityFooOutput> Result { ... }
}

// everything's strongly-typed from here on

var result = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke<ActivityFooOutput>(activity);

decimal d = result.Bar;
string s result.Baz;
```

Actually, if you don't want to create a custom type for it, you can use said tuples:

```
// generated

public System.Activities.OutArgument<Tuple<decimal, string>> Result { ... }

// everything's strongly-typed from here on

var result = WorkflowInvoker.Invoke<Tuple<decimal, string>>(activity);

decimal d = result.Item1;
string s result.Item2;
```

Being the first option obviously more scalable and verbose.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that there are multiple out values. The return from `Invoke` is an `IDictionary<string, object>` and I'm trying to see if I can get the values from the activity's properties rather than using strings to access the dictionary.